# The formula of neural networks in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network

I am learning the formula of neural networks in Keras. Suppose that I have a one-layer neural network and specific weights. (I know that we give the weights randomly in practice.) See the following diagram.

[image]

According to the formula which I learned, the loss is [(7-8)^2+(16-9)^2]/2=25. However, the real result is 15.
`1/1 [==============================] - 0s 202ms/step - loss: 15.0000`
See the following code.

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import initializers

import numpy as np

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(units=2, 
                       activation=None,
                       kernel_initializer=initializers.constant(np.array([3,5])),
                       bias_initializer=initializers.constant(np.array([4,6])),
                      )
         )

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mse',
             )

x = np.array([
              [1],
              [2]
             ])

y = np.array([
              [8],
              [9]
             ])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=1)
model.layers[0].weights
```

What point do I misunderstand?

Comment: Let's first clarify what are you trying to predict. Are you trying to predict 2 samples with 1 feature and 1 output, or 1 sample with 2 features and 2 output? or something else?

Comment: @Kaveh 2 samples, 2 outputs. What's a feature? Do you mean a predictor?

Comment: So, you want to get for an input number one output, e.g. 1 as input should output 8, and 2 should output 9. So, you don't have 2 outputs. you have 1 output. number of outputs is counted based on what you expect for each input. Therefore, 2 neurons for output layer is wrong.

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks. But it got an error if I change ```units=2``` to ```units=1```. In addition, how it get ```loss=15```?

Comment: Yes. you will get error, because the shape of kernel and biases is incompatible with 1 neuron. Why you get 15 as the loss, is relatively long story, since your NN architecture you have drawn in the above image is wrong. The input has 1 circle, and the second layer has 2 circles. So, 2 outputs are there. use this formula I think may help you `tf.keras.losses.MSE([[8],[9]], [model.predict([1]), model.predict([2])])`. You will get 2 outputs for each input, then the loss also will be 2. you can then get mean of them.

Comment: @Kaveh Ok. I see. Thanks.

Comment: @Kaveh Hello. Do you know which books I can learn the reason why the loss is 15?

Comment: I added an answer to explain how 15 is calculated as loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somehow difficult to explain, because your architecture is incorrect.

Let's go step by step:

1. You have defined single layer as input and output with 2 neurons. So, your model will predict 2 values, for each input.

```
>>> model.predict([1])
    array([[ 7., 11.]], dtype=float32) #for input 1, model gives 2 output: 7 and 11
>>> model.predict([2])
    array([[ 10., 16.]], dtype=float32) #for input 2, model gives 2 output: 10 and 16
```

2. Now, let's explore how the above output computed. You have set 2 weights 3,5 and 2 biases: 4,6. The architecture will be like below:

[image: arch]

3. Now, Let's compute the loss. The point is that, your model, outputs for each input, 2 outputs. So, you should provide 4 values as `y_true`, but you have provided 2 values `[8,9]` as ground truth values. Anyway, you feed two inputs: `[1,2]` to your model. and the model outputs 4 values: `[[7,11][10,16]]`, and `model.evaluate` outputs 15.0 as loss:

```
>>> x, y = np.array([[1],[2]]), np.array([[8],[9]])
>>> model.evaluate(x,y, verbose=2)
    1/1 - 0s - loss: 15.0000
```

Let's see how it is computed. From previous calculation you saw the `y_pred` is: `[[7,11][10,16]]` and you specified `y_true` as `[[8][9]]`. If we compute the loss of `y_true` vs. `y_pred` with `mse`:

```
>>> print(tf.keras.losses.mse([[8],[9]], [[[ 7., 11.]], [[10. ,16.]]]).numpy())
    [[ 5.  4.]
     [34. 25.]]
```

Now, we have 4 values as loss, 2 values for first input, and 2 values for second input. As the evaluate function expects you have 1 loss corresponding to each input, it picks fist value of first row as loss value for first input: picks `5.` in `[5.,4.]` as the loss for `1`, and picks in second row the second value for your second input: picks `25.` as the loss for `2`.
Now, if we sum them up and get average: `(25+5)/2=15.0`, it will be 15 which shows as result.

This complication is due to define architecture and passing values incorrectly.

You can generate more examples and compare them, e.g. feed 2 samples `1` and `2` as input and define `y_true` as `[6,7]`:

```
print("y_true: ", "[[ 6. 7. ]]")
print("y_pred: ", model.predict([1]))
print("loss:   ", tf.keras.losses.mse([[6.],[7.]], [model.predict([1])]).numpy())
print()
print("y_true: ", "[[ 6. 7. ]]")
print("y_pred: ", model.predict([2]))
print("loss:   ", tf.keras.losses.mse([[6.],[7.]], [model.predict([2])]).numpy())
x = np.array([[1],[2]])
y = np.array([[6],[7]])
model.evaluate(x,y,verbose=2)
print(tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.mse([[6],[7]], [model.predict([1]), model.predict([2])])).numpy())
```

the output is:

```
y_true:  [[ 6. 7. ]]
y_pred:  [[ 7. 11.]]
loss:    [[13.  8.]]

y_true:  [[ 6. 7. ]]
y_pred:  [[10. 16.]]
loss:    [[58. 45.]]
1/1 - 0s - loss: 29.0  #(45+13)/2      = 29.0  what model.evaluate() compute
                 31.0  #(58+45+13+8)/4 = 31.0  what probably you expect
```